# Command gets cut in half at the character of ampersand &?

Tags: php, linux, bash

A command like this:

```
php ~/xxxxxxx/csv/csv_to_datafy_project.php csv_file="/xxxxxx/Dentists~558564~26761~(Emails, Phone, Website) ~ United States.csv.category=Dental Equipment & Supplies.csv"
```

Which would result in some error like this:

```
File not exists: /home/n3a6/DATAFY/1/Dentists~558564~26761~(Emails, Phone, Website) ~ United States.csv.category=Dental Equipment
```

It seems the ampersand cuts the supplied parameter in half. Why?

Thus far I tried \& and && but nothing helped.

How can I escape it in such a situation?

Comment: It's correct from the bash point of view. It's probably a bug in the PHP script. Do you control it or are you trying to work around this bug?

Comment: try `csv_file=%2Fxxxxxx%2FDentists~558564~26761~%28Emails%2C%20Phone%2C%20Website%29%20~%20United%20States.csv&category=Dental%20Equipment%20%26%20Supplies.csv`

Comment: Did you copy-and-paste the exact error message? Neither the shell nor `php` would use the phrase "File not exists" (it's incorrect English grammar), though your script `csv_to_datafy_project.php` might.

Comment: @LéaGris you are right. Please write an answer and I'll accept it. It's related to my PHP code rather than Bash.